# How to disabled Angular mat-tab animations between two different component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a component inside my main-content component called answer-form component.
My second component(answer-form) is in mat-tab.

**While the questions should slide with the animation, the buttons should stay in place.**

This is answer-form.component.html

```
<div class="button-toggle-form-field">
  <p>{{ question?.name }}</p>
  <mat-button-toggle-group (change)="onValueSelected($event.value)" #buttonGroup>
    <mat-button-toggle value="true" [checked]="answer === true">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="false" [checked]="answer === false">No</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

This is main-content.component.html mat-tab part

```
      <mat-tab  *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index" >
        <div *ngIf="onStage == i + 1">
          <app-answer-form [question]="question" [answer]="getAnswerByQuestionId(question.id)">
          </app-answer-form>
        </div>
      </mat-tab>
```

enter image description here

[THIS IS THE VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7N5g.png)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div [@.disabled]="true">
 <mat-button-toggle-group (change)="onValueSelected($event.value)" #buttonGroup>
    <mat-button-toggle value="true" [checked]="answer === true">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="false" [checked]="answer === false">No</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```